# jQuery Function Not Executing in IE9

Tags: jquery

Currently building a site that uses jQuery Masonry from Desandro with the Infinite Scroll built in.  Works brilliantly in every browser except IE (even IE7 and IE8 work just fine).  It appears that jQuery(function) is not executing at all.  I've tested by placing an alert inside but never executes.  There is no error displayed in IE Developer.

Here is my code and a link to the site: http://www.elke.co/testimonials/

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(function () {
    var $container = jQuery('#sort');

    $container.imagesLoaded(function () {

      $container.masonry({
        itemSelector: '.box',
        columnWidth: 100
      });
    });

    $container.infinitescroll({
      navSelector: '.navigation', // selector for the paged navigation 
      nextSelector: '.navigation .nav-previous a', // selector for the NEXT link (to page 2)
      itemSelector: '.box', // selector for all items you'll retrieve
      loading: {
        finishedMsg: 'No more pages to load.',
        img: 'http://www.elke.co/wp-content/themes/shaken-grid-free/images/ajax-loader.gif'
      }
    },
    // trigger Masonry as a callback
    function (newElements) {
      // hide new items while they are loading
      var $newElems = jQuery(newElements).css({
        opacity: 0
      });
      // ensure that images load before adding to masonry layout
      $newElems.imagesLoaded(function () {
        // show elems now they're ready
        $newElems.animate({
          opacity: 1
        });

        $container.masonry('appended', $newElems, true);
      });
    });
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In chrome I'm seeing:

`Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL http://www.elke.co/testimonials/ from frame with URL http://www.youtube.com/embed/g3V26BQ85IM. Domains, protocols and ports must match.`

Some sort of AJAX cross-domain must be done wrong and IE security is simply denying the request, others are letting it slide.

Comment: I think you're correct. It has to do with the security settings in IE9.